# Revert removeAttr in js or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which have more than 800 child's and they have random Id's.
I want to remove all Id attributes in that main div and after an event revert it to the default one.

I had used jQuery `removeAttr()` method for deleting all child's ID's but I am not able to bring the Id's back to its default one and as they are lots of elements I can't use `attr()` to add them one by one.

Update 1:
I'm doing this because its an SVG animation file which have lots of elements an I want to trigger the animations on some events.
Some declaration :
The main div is like this:

```
<div id="#mainSVG">
<svg>
<g id="random123"></g>
<g id="random235"></g>
<g id="random183"></g>
and so on ...
</svg>
</div>
```

and my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
  let hT = $('.home-anim-1').offset().top,
    hH = $('.home-anim-1').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    $("div #el_hXoVA5SDrei_an_ISJE0y5YL *").removeAttr("id")
  }else {
    $("div #el_hXoVA5SDrei_an_ISJE0y5YL *") I want to bring back all ids that are deleted
  }
  });
})
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need to remove those `id` attributes? ... And why you need those `id` attributes in the first place?

Comment: `random id's` ... That doesn't sound too good. Make sure they are unique.

Comment: What's your accompanying HTML code?

Comment: This sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you reassigning IDs like this?

Comment: Its and Svg file and I'm adding some events to this animated svg

Comment: @MohammadGhonchesefidi make your animation based on the Class selector not the id, you can't "save" the id values without iterating over all elements. Simply `add/removeClass()`

Comment: Once you delete it, it is gone. So there is no way to just toggle it. You would need to store the original value in a data attribute and restore it. But whatever you are doing sounds weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing the `id` of an element, the old value it had isn't remembered anywhere by default. You can remember it somewhere, though, when removing it: a `data-*` attribute using [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) or jQuery's data cache using [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
// Attribute
theElement.attr("data-original-id", theElement.attr("id")).attr("id", newValue);
// Or jQuery's `data` store
theElement.data("original-id", theElement.attr("id")).attr("id", newValue);
```

Then later, to restore it, just put that value back:

```
// Attribute
theElement.attr("id", theElement.attr("data-original-id"));
// Or jQuery's `data` store
theElement.attr("id", theElement.data("original-id"));
```

If doing that in a loop, you can use the callback versions of those.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thing I got how should I handle my problem

Answer (score 1):

you can rename the attribute in order to save it, to restore you can set the Id back in your element...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
  let hT = $('.home-anim-1').offset().top,
    hH = $('.home-anim-1').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    $("div #el_hXoVA5SDrei_an_ISJE0y5YL *").each(function(){
       $(this).attr(savedId:$(this).attr("id")).removeAttr("id")
    });
  }else {
    $("div #el_hXoVA5SDrei_an_ISJE0y5YL *").each(function(){
       $(this).attr(id:$(this).attr("savedId")).removeAttr("savedId")
    });
  }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. It stores the `id` of the `div` in an `array` and then sequentially provides the `value` again when `id` attributes are added

```js
var a=[];
var i=-1;
$('#main > div').each(function(){a.push($(this).attr('id'))})
console.log("The id's are  " + [...a])
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#remove').click(function(){$('#main > div').each(function(){$(this).removeAttr('id')})})

$('#add').click(function(){$('#main > div').each(function(){$(this).attr('id',a[++i])})})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
</div>

<button id="remove">remove</button>
<button id="add">add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To save (hold old values) of the all ids you will have to iterate over all this elements, and if you don't want to do that. I would recommend you using `class` selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
  let hT = $('.home-anim-1').offset().top,
    hH = $('.home-anim-1').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    $("div #el_hXoVA5SDrei_an_ISJE0y5YL *").addClass("wS_is_bigger_than_X")
  }else {
    $("div #el_hXoVA5SDrei_an_ISJE0y5YL *").removeClass("wS_is_bigger_than_X")
  }

  // or simply toggleClass
  // $("div #el_hXoVA5SDrei_an_ISJE0y5YL *").toggleClass("wS_is_bigger_than_X", wS > (hT + hH - wH));
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just explained my problem in simplest way I can. you suggestion about using class is not my approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function RemoveId(){
 $('#parent >').each(function(){
         $(this).attr("data-id",$(this).attr("id")).attr("id","");
    });
}
function ResetId(){
 $('#parent >').each(function(){
         $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("data-id")).attr("data-id","");
    });
}
</script>
<div id="parent"> 
  <div id="id_1">1</div>
  <div id="id_2">2</div>
  <div id="id_3">3</div>
  <div id="id_4">4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="RemoveId();">RemoveId</button>
<button onclick="ResetId();">ResetId</button>
```